# SharePoint 2016 Full Crawl is only running for 10 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have re-created our farms Search Application Service due to corruption when applying patches. The new application worked and a first full crawl took 36 hours to complete.

It was then noticed that some refiners had been lost, so 3 new managed properties were re-added and then we have tried to run a full crawl again. Every single full crawl since then has only run for on average 10 minutes. The crawl log shows errors but, nothing to indicate why the crawl only lasts 10 mins. We have tried to remove some sites from the content source, cleared timer cache and double checked the service account we are using, but still no change.

We have not tried IIS Resets on each server, or server reboots, or restart/re-provision the search application - are these the next steps to try?

Are they any other logs we should be looking at?

Comment: have you checked the permissions for the crawl user account? If it doesn't have access, it'll assume it's crawled everything and finish

Comment: So, what's in crawl logs? What kind of errors? Does it contain top-level errors? Make sure that _Search Topology Statistics - Search Service Application_ timer job are completing successfully.